# How to trim text with PHP?

Tags: php, string, trim

I have a problem trimming some text with PHP. I had a text that looked something like that:

```
$teams = "team1-team2"
```

I needed to trim it so I get the first team and the second one and I did so by using this piece of code:

```
$team1= substr($teams, 0, strpos($teams, "-"));

$team2= substr($teams, strpos($teams, '-') + 1);
```

However now I have something like this: `team1-team2-team3`

How could I trim the string so I get the teams like I did before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [explode()](http://php.net/explode) function. For example:

```
$teams = explode("-", "team1-team2-team3");

echo $teams[0]; // prints "team1"
echo $teams[1]; // prints "team2"
echo $teams[2]; // prints "team3"
```

Answer (score 0):

You use "explode" function of php with character to explode string